# Можно ли захватить медиазапрос с помощью JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Хочу привязать к кнопке событие, которое отключит медиазапрос. Можно ли это реализовать и как?

Answer (score 3):

Можно прописать медиазапрос для некоего класса и по клику добавлять/удалять этот класс у нужных элементов.

А можно вынести медиазапрос в отдельный css-файл и по клику удалять/возвращать значение href у соответствующего link.

Это так, навскидку. Наверное, есть и другие варианты.